# How to decode CSR (PKCS #10) using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, x509, csr

I have the file:

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIDPzCCAqgCAQAwZDELMAkGA1UEBhMCQ04xCzAJBgNVBAgTAmJqMQswCQYDVQQH
EwJiajERMA8GA1UEChMIbXhjei5uZXQxETAPBgNVBAsTCG14Y3oubmV0MRUwEwYD
VQQDEwx3d3cubXhjei5uZXQwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAMQ7
an4v6pHRusBA0prMWXMWJCXY1AO1H0X8pvZj96T5GWg++JPCQE9guPgGwlD02U0B
NDoEABeD1fwyKZ+JV5UFiOeSjO5sWrzIupdMI7hf34UaPNxHo6r4bLYEykw/Rnmb
GKnNcD4QlPkypE+mLR4p0bnHZhe3lOlNtgd6NpXbAgMBAAGgggGZMBoGCisGAQQB
gjcNAgMxDBYKNS4yLjM3OTAuMjB7BgorBgEEAYI3AgEOMW0wazAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E
BAMCBPAwRAYJKoZIhvcNAQkPBDcwNTAOBggqhkiG9w0DAgICAIAwDgYIKoZIhvcN
AwQCAgCAMAcGBSsOAwIHMAoGCCqGSIb3DQMHMBMGA1UdJQQMMAoGCCsGAQUFBwMB
MIH9BgorBgEEAYI3DQICMYHuMIHrAgEBHloATQBpAGMAcgBvAHMAbwBmAHQAIABS
AFMAQQAgAFMAQwBoAGEAbgBuAGUAbAAgAEMAcgB5AHAAdABvAGcAcgBhAHAAaABp
AGMAIABQAHIAbwB2AGkAZABlAHIDgYkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOBgQBIKHVhHb9FZdVLV4VZ
9DK4aBSuYY//jlIpvsfMIdHXfAsuan7w7PH87asp1wdb6lD9snvLZix1UGK7VQg6
wUFYNlMqJh1m7ITVvzhjdnx7EzCKkBXSxEom4mwbvSNvzqOKAWsDE0gvHQ9aCSby
NFBQQMoW94LqrG/kuIQtjwVdZA==
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

How can I decode it in Ruby to obtain the following information that is part of the request subject?

- Common name: www.somedomain.com
- Organization:someorg.com
- Organizational unit:someunit.com
- City/locality:bj
- State/province:bj
- Country:CN

Comment: Luckily, Ruby comes with an [`OpenSSL`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) module which wraps the [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) library.

Comment: RubyOpenSSL can [generate](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/blob/4eda40878fc42ac5bad6dd7b1ebc8f0eac796b94/sample/gen_csr.rb) CSR, but there is no decoding method there.

Comment: What about `OpenSSL::X509::Request.new(your_request_data)`?

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem.

P.S. `OpenSSL::X509::Request.new(File.open("/my/file.csr").read)`

Comment: That will leave you with an open file handle, use `File.read('/my/file.csr')` instead.

Comment: And feel free to provide an answer to your question (it's okay to answer your own question). I'd like to know how you managed to extract the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  def parse_csr(file_path)
    csr = OpenSSL::X509::Request.new(File.read(file_path))
    # puts csr.subject.to_a
    # => [["C", "RU", 19], ["ST", "State", 12], ["L", "City", 12], ["O", "CompanyName", 12], ["OU", "Unit", 12], ["CN", "App 1.0", 12], ["emailAddress", "user@company.com", 22]]
    csr.subject.to_a.inject({}) do |r, s|
      r.merge!(s[0] => s[1])
    end
  end
```

**Output:**

```
=> {"C"=>"RU", "ST"=>"State", "L"=>"City", "O"=>"Company Name", "OU"=>"Unit", "CN"=>"App v1.0", "emailAddress"=>"user@company.com"}
```

Comment: Slightly shorter: `subject.to_a.each(&:pop).to_h`